# remove rows by conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to count the rows by conditions on multiple columns and remove the rows by the conditions.

I want to count the rows if `v1` and `v2` have the same value, such that my df has 2 rows on (v1=0, v2=30), 1 row on (v1 = 0, v2 = 15; v1 = 0, v2 = 20), 2 rows on (v1 = 15, v2 = 10), 3 rows on (v1 = 10, v2 = 10). Then remove the rows if the v1 and v2 don't have 2 rows, in this case, remove (v1 = 0, v2 = 15; v1 = 0, v2 = 20) and (v1 = 10, v2 = 10).

df

```
 ID    v1    v2
  1    0     30
  1    15    10
  1    0     30
  1    0     15
  1    0     20
  1    15    10
  1    10    10
  1    10    10
  1    10    10
```

expected output

```
 ID    v1    v2
  1    0     30
  1    0     30
  1    15    10
  1    15    10
```

I `groupby` the values first, but not sure what conditions should I write for the removal.

```
df[df.groupby(['ID', 'v_1', 'v_2'])]
```

Hope I explain clearly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[29]: 
   ID  v1  v2
0   1   0  30
1   1  15  10
2   1   0  30
5   1  15  10
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, `duplicated` seems a quick function. But what if my dataframe has other duplicated rows, but I only need the ones with duplication of 2? Sorry that I wasn't clear on that in my question, I will edit it.

Comment: @Kay i will not change my answer ,you can try `df[df.groupby(['ID','v1','v2']).ID.transform('count')==2]
`